# Disabling form controls via $(":input") causes @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to fail MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line in my code which I've found to be responsible for causing my `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to not be found/be invalid when posting:

`$(':input, select').not('#StartDate, #RemainingPayments, #ToReference, #FromReference, #btnSave').prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Changing the `'disabled'` to `'readonly'` fixes the error.

I wanted to have the controls disabled because with `Html.Dropdown's` and the `bootstrap datepicker` I'm using, just changing the fields to `readonly` doesn't actually stop you from changing those fields.

Can anyone explain why this causes the error included below?

`The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.`

I know that by disabling a field you stop that field's value from being posted back to the server, but I was expecting a null value for the specific fields I'm disabling.

I'm planning on replacing the `:'input'` syntax with specific tags and see if that makes a difference but I would still like to understand this either way. I would think it weird that something generated by the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` would be a control that's collected by the `:'input'` tag..?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding Hidden fields for properties you want to post.

Comment: frogery token is rednered as hidden field what i think so it it also not posted due to disabl

Comment: exclude hidden fields as well

Comment: Thanks guys that's fixed it. Just didn't click that it was rendered as hidden. Much appreciated.